# Why or How? Which one do we prefer more in philosophy?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mind

Why or How?
 Which one of them do we use in Philosophy to understand and describe the world around us? More simply, which one do we prefer more and why? In physics, more likely, we use HOW to know how things really are around us. But I don't know which it is in Philosophy.

Comment: I don't think that the question is too broad. But it needs more effort.

Comment: You may want to look at Aristotle, Thomas Aquinas, Jacques Maritain, if you have these interests. Here are some readings in the subject. https://maritain.nd.edu/jmc/aristotl.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though both of these words have very great significance in philosophy, when philosophy is just for thinking and analyzing I would give more preference to 'Why'. But when it comes to application level I would give **equal importance** to 'How' also.

You may choose this question itself a sample and verify whether more sensible questions regarding this come under 'Why' or 'How'.